# Azure DevOps Server , unable to change work item type

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have upgraded the on premise TFS 2018 server to on premise Azure DevOps Server 2020,
There is a new option in 2020 to change the work item type (Change type):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops

But in is not visible on the work item ( or any other location):

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using TFS on-premise, so you cannot use this feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops#change-the-work-item-type

[image]